# Как вычесть массивы?

Tags: php

Есть два массива, к примеру:

```
[0=>52, 1=>45, 2=>58]
```

и

```
[38=>47, 78=>68, 45=>85]
```

Нужно из второго массива вычесть элементы, ключи которых присутствуют в значениях первого массива. В данном примере это третий элемент массива, ключ которого - 45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под вычесть вы понимаете "удалить", то можно просто перебрать элементы первого, и проверить наличие ключей во втором.

```
$first = [52, 45, 58];
$second = [38=>47, 78=>68, 45=>85];

foreach($first as $f){
    unset($second[$f]);
}
```

второй вариант, взять расхождение массивов по ключам, первый массив для этого надо "перевернуть"

```
$first = array_flip($first);
$second = array_diff_key($second, $first);
```

и далее  насколько фантазии хватит.